# $\frac{ra}{p} + \frac{rb}{p} + \frac{rc}{p} + \frac{rd}{p} = 2 $, with $p$ prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p>2$ be a prime and let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be integers not divisible by $p$, 
such that $\{\frac{ra}{p}\} + \{\frac{rb}{p}\} + \{\frac{rc}{p}\} + \{\frac{rd}{p}\} = 2 $
for any integer $r$ not divisible by $p$.

Prove that at least two of the numbers $a+b$ , $a+c$ , $a+d$ , $b+c$ , $b+d$ , $c+d$ are divisible by $p$.

(Here for real number $x$, $\{x\}=x-[x]$ denotes the fractional part of $x$)

Comment: I presume you mean 'for _some_ integer $r$' and not 'for _every_ integer $r$'?

Comment: the question says for any integer r that is not divisible by p

Comment: I remember this problem is America Mathematical Olympiad

Comment: Can you find the solution for this? which year of AMO?

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=340038&sid=1ded6289ea007274c285889829935609#p340038